# How can I ignore the date picker when I press down in date field

Tags: extjs4

I have a date field in ExtJS 4, and I want to add a custom event to the down arrow key, but the date field shows the picker and lost focus on pressing down arrow on keyboard. How can I disable this event to use only my event?

Thx for answers!

```
specialkey: function (t, e, opts) {
    console.log(e.getKey());
    var key = e.getKey();
    this.keyEvents(t, key);
}
```

...

```
keyEvents: function (t, key) {
    switch(key){
        case 38: // up
            break;
        case 40: // down // picker off??????
            break;
        case 37: // left
            break;
        case 39: // right
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest would be to create a subclass of date field and override the down handling method:

```
Ext.define('MyDate', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Date',
    alias: 'widget.mydate',
    onDownArrow: Ext.emptyFn
});
```

Comment: onDownArrow, this is! Thank you!